# How come I get a syntax error when using a CTE to update a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column (share_2pp) that needs to be updated with a calculated result from the table. This select query produces the column (share_2pp) I would like.

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT recipe
    , SUM(meal_nr) AS meal_sum
    FROM w03_forecast
    GROUP BY recipe
    )
SELECT w03_forecast.recipe
    , w03_forecast.meal_nr
    , meal_sum
    , (meal_nr / meal_sum) AS share_2pp
FROM w03_forecast
INNER JOIN cte
ON w03_forecast.recipe = cte.recipe;
```

```
+--------+---------+----------+-----------+
| recipe | meal_nr | meal_sum | share_2pp |
+--------+---------+----------+-----------+
|      1 |    3842 |     4593 |    0.8365 |
|      2 |    4284 |     5130 |    0.8351 |
|      3 |    4166 |     4926 |    0.8457 |
|      4 |    2830 |     3382 |    0.8368 |
|      5 |    2495 |     2935 |    0.8501 |
|      1 |     751 |     4593 |    0.1635 |
|      2 |     846 |     5130 |    0.1649 |
|      3 |     760 |     4926 |    0.1543 |
|      4 |     552 |     3382 |    0.1632 |
|      5 |     440 |     2935 |    0.1499 |
+--------+---------+----------+-----------+
```

However, when I try to update the table I get a syntax error at FROM.

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT recipe
    , SUM(meal_nr) AS meal_sum
    FROM w03_forecast
    GROUP BY recipe
    )
UPDATE w03_forecast
SET w03_forecast.share_2pp = (meal_nr / meal_sum)
FROM w03_forecast
INNER JOIN cte
ON w03_forecast.recipe = cte.recipe;
```

Comment: See UPDATE syntax

Comment: Apart from the incorrect update syntax see Multiple-table syntax:in manual, update with cte is not supported.

Comment: @P.Salmon That's not true. The datasource in multiple-table UPDATE may be a subquery which may contain CTE.

Comment: @Akina  do you have an example?

Comment: @P.Salmon Please: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=696b12aaf5f21eae32028cef975b2340). Of course CTE may refer to separate (not updated) copy of updated table or previous CTE.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE w03_forecast f JOIN
       (SELECT recipe, SUM(meal_nr) AS meal_sum
        FROM w03_forecast
        GROUP BY recipe
       ) r
       USING (recipe)
    SET f.share_2pp = (meal_nr / meal_sum);
```

That said, there is no reason to store this in the table.  It can easily be calculated on-the-fly using window functions:

```
select f.*,
       (meal_nr / sum(meal_nr) over ()) as share_2pp
from w03_forecast f
```

Comment: Thanks, using OVER() and PARTITION helps with the SELECT query. I'm still not sure of the syntax for how that is used to UPDATE. This is what I have. But I keep having syntax errors. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc4cab/1